# Get taxonomy values based on wp_query results

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

We are building an extension for displaying vacancies. On the overview page of the vacancies we display filters (taxonomies) which are used for filtering the results. We do this by adding a tax_query to wp_query. This works fine for the results but we only want to display the taxonomies/taxonomy value in the filter list if it exists in the result-set. So, if we for example filter on "Region" = "Canada" we do not want to display the other regions since they do not exist in the result-set. So, I would like to count the taxonomy/taxonomy-value from the wp_query results and only display as filter if > 0. Only, I cannot find a way to do this. So bottomline I would like to get taxonomies/taxonomy values based on the result of wp_query. Any tips?

Comment: Do you have a code example of what you currently have? What's your loop look like? If you're working with taxonomy filters could you use `get_terms()` and check against `$term->count`?

Comment: What you're describing is "faceted search". It's going to be fairly complicated to implement, but maybe that term will help you find a solution if one isn't provided here. Ultimately it will be easier to implement if you use a plugin like ElasticPress or FacetWP. Any solution that would fit inside an answer here will not be very performant, because you'll get the best results by creating an index of your content in a different format.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will check and when we find a solution, I will post here.